# Yahoo finance feed for an specific date

Tags: api, rss, feed, yahoo, finance

I am currently working on an app that needs news for stock companies for older dates. For example the following gives only recent news:

http://feeds.finance.yahoo.com/rss/2.0/headline?s=WALMEXV.MX&region=US&lang=en-US

Is it possible to get news for an specific date to retrieve older ones?

Comment: Did you get any solution for this?

Comment: I ended up using other API (bloomberg or reuters cannot recall which one) since it provided the info I needed

Answer (score 2):

Reuters has good news.

If you're not averse to a bit of web-scraping, you could parameterise the stock symbol in this URL:

- http://www.reuters.com/finance/stocks/companyNews?symbol=AAPL.O

and then add the date:

- http://www.reuters.com/finance/stocks/companyNews?symbol=AAPL.O&date=01082014

Comment: good onee, i kind of like Reuters better anyway :) by the ways also works for some firms form the mexican stock market